# "grid-template-columns: fit-content(50%) 1fr;" doesn't work as expected

Tags: css

My application has an element that contains two range items (title and description). I would like the title width to be larger compared to the description width, but if the title is too large, limit it so that the description also appears.
My solution ([full code here](https://codepen.io/perevezencev/pen/GRqoNxV))

```
.info {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: fit-content(50%) 1fr;
  overflow: hidden;
  
  margin-bottom: 20px
}
```

but this solution have a problem with the case where the title is long and the description is too short.
[image]
It works differently in my application. ([code here](https://codepen.io/perevezencev/pen/ZEOQLYo))
[image]
If there is no description, the title width is still 50%.

How to implement this, maybe there is an easier way?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.info {
  display: flex;
  align-items: left;
  text-align: left;
}

.title {
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  max-width: 50%;
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
}

.description {
  color: #67697c;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 16px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <section class="info">
    <div class="title">
      short title
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      shor description
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="info">
    <div class="title">
      short title
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      long description - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque nec quam nulla. In eu dui faucibus, euismod urna eu, consequat elit.
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="info">
    <div class="title">
      long title - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque nec quam nulla. In eu dui faucibus, euismod urna eu, consequat elit.
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      short description
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="info">
    <div class="title">
      long title - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque nec quam nulla. In eu dui faucibus, euismod urna eu, consequat elit.
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      long description - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque nec quam nulla. In eu dui faucibus, euismod urna eu, consequat elit.
    </div>
  </section>
  <div class="title">
    long title without description - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque nec quam nulla. In eu dui faucibus, euismod urna eu, consequat elit.
  </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

I have added flex in the parent div and I gave 50% max-width for title.

Comment: your solution has 2 problems: 1) in the absence of a description, the maximum title width is 50% 2) in the case of a long description and a short title, the title will be shortened (although it shouldn't)